# HTML list falls apart with chrome

Tags: html, css

The following code runs well with firefox, but falls apart with chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tYfY/4/

```
<body>
    <div id="footer"><ul>
<li class=""><a href="rolunk">1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="hotelek">2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="apartmanok">3</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="impresszum">4</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div>
</body>

.clear, .clearfix{clear:both;}

#footer
{
    background-image: url('../images/footerLoopBg.png');
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}
#footer ul li a
{
    color: #DB9FBD;
}
#footer li:after
{
    content: '|';
    padding: 5px;
    color: #DB9FBD;
}
#footer li:last-of-type:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: OK. And your question?

Comment: Welcome in the tough world of webdesigners

Comment: check my answer. You dont need to change css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
#footer ul li { vertical-align: top;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tYfY/5/)

Comment: This is just a visual solution .. if you inspect the element on chrome you can see the 4 element stills more bigger than the others try adding a bg

Comment: Yes, and last li element still have its :after pseudo element on bottom. It will surely cause other problems on the layout.

Comment: @Danko that comes from his footer 'line-height: 70px;' if he removes it it will be ok or overwrite it on the ul for example. But the question was about alignment of the list items.

Comment: It isn't the line-height: http://jsfiddle.net/4tYfY/27/ is the after element of the last li..

Comment: @Danko ok + the after on the last element. That can be done with borders but that is his choice.

Comment: I just want to make the anotation for future users that see this question because like @enguerranws say the real issue can cause other problems.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmisravani/4tYfY/14/)

```
#footer ul li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that two things work for this fix you can add:

```
    #footer ul li 
       { 
         vertical-align: top;
       }
```

or remove

```
content: "";
```

Comment: the "content" is needed, thx, somebody gave the answer faster :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is when you remove the `content` for the last item:

```
#footer li:last-of-type:after {
  content: "";
}
```

In a better way try this:

```
#footer li:last-of-type:after {
  display:none;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/4tYfY/24/**

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to change css. There is nothing wrong in your css. There is something wrong in your html. See code below

```
<body>
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li class="">   <a href="rolunk">1</a></li>
        <li class="">   <a href="hotelek">2</a></li>
        <li class="">   <a href="apartmanok">3</a></li>
        <li class="">   <a href="impresszum">4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4tYfY/21/). I have not changed any css.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the last li element still have an :after pseudo-element. So, even if that after element has no more "|", it still is an element width a padding of 5px.

In order to fix it :

```
#footer li:last-of-type:after {
  display: none;
}
```